# Split the window vertically in XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to split my window in 2 parts side by side, like the picture below. On each side I have a `SwapChainPanel` and a `StackPanel` with a `TextBlock`, a `TextBox` and a `Button`.

Below that, I have a console (`TextBlock`) which takes up the entire width of the window.

[image: Window composition scheme]

How can I do that in XAML?

I have this but it does not split the window into 2 equal parts:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        <SwapChainPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <TextBlock />
                <TextBox />
                <Button />
            </StackPanel>
        </SwapChainPanel>

        <SwapChainPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <TextBlock />
                <TextBox />
                <Button />
            </StackPanel>
        </SwapChainPanel>

    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <TextBlock />
    </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StackPanel` are for stacking Items One after another or one below another. So you will not get exact split. For that you Need to use `Grid`.

I marked up a basic XAML based on your Screenshot.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5,5,2.5,5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <SwapChainPanel BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="SwapChainPanel_L" Foreground="Blue" Margin="20"/>
            </SwapChainPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0">
                <TextBlock Text="IP Address 1: " Foreground="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Width="150" Margin="5,0"/>
                <Button Content="Connect" Margin="5,0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2.5,5,5,5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <SwapChainPanel BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="SwapChainPanel_R" Foreground="Blue" Margin="20"/>
            </SwapChainPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0">
                <TextBlock Text="IP Address 2: " Foreground="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Width="150" Margin="5,0"/>
                <Button Content="Connect" Margin="5,0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,5,0,0" Padding="5">
        <TextBox Text="> Console" Foreground="Green" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Which Renders to

[image]